# Reset selectOneMenu form value after validation failure

Tags: java, validation, jsf, primefaces

We are attempting to use a selectOneMenu as a "status" control for a business entity. The dropdown has a list of statuses. When the user selects a status, we run a set of complex business rules that determine whether the selected status is ok to set on the business entity. If it's not, we write out a message why not, and disallow the status from being set. This all works well within the JSF lifecycle, except that I would like to reset the dropdown to the previous status (aka the current status) before the validation failed. So if I switch from status A, to status B, but fail, I want to reset the form control to status B.

## facelet code

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="statusMenu"
    binding="#{mybean.statusMenu}"
    converter="myConverter"
    value="#{mybean.statusValue}">

    <f:event type="preValidate" listener="#{mybean.validateStatus}"/>
    <p:ajax update="statusMenu :someForm :someOtherForm" />

    <f:selectItems value="#{mybean.statusList}"
        var="status"
        itemLabel="#{status.statusText}"
        itemValue="#{status}">
    </f:selectItems>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

## Backing bean validation menu

```
public void validateStatus (ComponentSystemEvent e)
{
    String submittedStatus = ((MyStatus)getStatusMenu().getValue()).getStatusText();

    if(submittedStatus.equals("someStatus"))
    {       
        //do validation
        boolean valid = doBusinessStatusValidationLogicStuff()

        if(!valid)
        {
            //a combination of junk that attempts to reset the form value, or do *something* to it
            getStatusMenu().resetValue();
            getStatusMenu().setSubmittedValue(null);
            getStatusMenu().setValue(null);
            getStatusMenu().setLocalValueSet(false);

            FacesMessage errorMessage = new FacesMessage(severity, summary, detail);
            context.addMessage(null, "you fail");
            context.isValidationFailed();
            context.renderResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

I can see in the debugger that the bound component's value is set to what I want, however it simply does not update the form control. What am I missing?

Comment: make sure your managed bean its ViewScoped instead of RequestScoped

Comment: the managedbean is sessionscoped, so shouldn't be any problems there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up being an equals/hashcode issue. So always be sure to check there!